# can i write a opengl es 2.0 for android 3.0?

Tags: android, opengl-es

i have just started working with opengl es 2.0 for android 3.x.x. But i am facing constant force close. I couldnt figure out the message in Log Cat. So i was just wondering if opengl es 2.0 is supported only in android 4.x?

Answer (score 1):

OpenGL es 2.0 is supported by Android OS 2.2 and up [**(source)**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html). The issue might lie elsewhere

Comment: bad coding probably. Let me reconfigure the opengl from github. Thanks